# B2C redirect after SSO login AADSTS50196

Tags: single-page-application, azure-ad-b2c

[image]

https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=XXXXXX&resource=http%3A%2F%2FXXXXXX%2Fweb%2Fapi&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FXXXXXXXX%2F&state=21902009-e598-47bb-852e-c1400132bdde%7Chttp%3A%2F%2FXXXXXXXX%2Fweb%2Fapi&prompt=none

Is this supposed to be a client bug or B2C missconfiguration?
I'm using a knockout SPA client and B2C custom policies.

I know it can be fixed clearing cookies or using a private window.

Someone faced this problem?

Should i review client code to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

"client request loop" error happens when an app makes too many requests to Azure AD in a short period of time (i.e. they are being throttled).

This most often happens if the application is not properly caching tokens so you may have to revisit your code.